# jQuery parent() function returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

I have the following html (simplified to basic setup):

```
<div class="findme">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="image" src="image.png" onclick="findTheDiv(event)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I click on the image, the `findTheDiv(event)` function runs, which looks like this:

```
function findTheDiv(event) {
  var elem = $(event.toElement);
  var found = false;
  // stop the loop if the top-level element is reached (html)
  while (!$(elem).is("html")) {
    if ($(elem).is("div.findme")) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
    elem = $(elem).parent();
    console.log(elem);
  }
}
```

This runs, and for each iteration of the while loop, I log the new elem, which is the previous element's parent, to the console.  This is the result I get:

```
[<img id="image" src="image.png" onclick="findTheDiv(event)">]
[<td>]
[<tr>]
[<table>]
[]
```

When the table is reached, it apparently has no parent, even though it clearly does, which is the `div`.  To further test this, I used the console to execute this:

```
$("table").parent();
```

And it returned a blank array

```
[]
```

Why is jQuery saying the table does not have a parent, since all elements except for the `<html>` have parents?

Comment: Not an issue, but you should replace all `$(elem)` with `elem`. `elem` already is a jQuery object.

Comment: try to add a console.log before the break;

Comment: ^ You know what break does? It terminates the loop. You are calling break when `div.findme` is found, before `console.log`. So you would never log that element.

Comment: @FelixKing - But the thing is, the loop never terminates, it goes on forever, and the page crashes.  So right now I just need the loop to find the element, and I can store the elem before the break

Comment: Why don't use `this` variable rather than `event` which makes your code more readable and standard? No need to pass args into the function! Your code looks like somewhat obscure:( like using `elem` variable twice!

Comment: Why not use $(elem).parents()?: `var elem = $(event.toElement).parents(".findme:first")`

Comment: @wZVanG - I tried `$(elem).parents()`, but the last element of the array is the table, and using the selector, it is an empty array

Comment: The code inside the div is generated when the page loads, the div is written blank. Would this cause this problem?

Comment: Here is jsfiddle that logs div normally. https://jsfiddle.net/rts3b3ad/

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Find the div with class `findme`, or list all the parent nodes?

Comment: @mef - I need to find the div, but there are multiple occurrences of this tree in my page, so just querying the class will not work

Comment: This code should be working. It is strange that you are getting this error. fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jxu84j83/

Comment: @mef - Actually, I need to know whether the element is in the div

Comment: Your code works fine for me on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjmNwj). Not sure why you're getting an error :(

Comment: @vcapra1 ok, I have just updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the jQuery `closest` function already provides the feature you are looking for, no need to reinvent the wheel:

```js
function findTheDiv(e) {
  var res = $(elem).closest('div.findme')
  if (res. length) {
    console.log('found it', res)
    return true
  }
  console.log('the image is not inside a `div.findme`')
  return false
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="findme">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="image" src="image.png" onclick="findTheDiv(this)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I really don't understand why this isn't working for me.  Your code looks like it should work, but for some reason it does not. There are many other elements in the `div.findme`, and all of those work as expected, giving an output of `'found it',` but the image is the only one that does not work.  And it is a sibling to the ones that are working!

Comment: I figured it out: the image had another click() method defined by jQuery that I had forgotten about, so it was calling that instead.  So this method does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a little and it works fine. Instead of using an `event` object as an argument, I just pass `this` to reference the object which fires the event directly. This serves the same purpose.

```js
function findTheDiv(elem) {
  //var elem = $(event.toElement);
  var found = false;
  // stop the loop if the top-level element is reached (html)
  while (!$(elem).is("html")) {
    if ($(elem).is("div.findme")) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
    elem = $(elem).parent();
    console.log(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="findme">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="image" src="image.png" onclick="findTheDiv(this)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Run the snippet, have your JavaScript console open and see what it logs.